# Convert an object into binary code and vice versa

Tags: c#, wpf, object, binary, converters

I want to save a object in my `MS Database`, but i can't save it without converting. So i asking here, if I can convert an `object` into `binary code` and vice versa.

Comment: search for binary serialization.

Comment: See [`BinaryFormatter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx).

Comment: Check [`Binary Serialization`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72hyey7b(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is called serializing the object. Check out this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1789/Object-Serialization-using-C

Answer (score 0):

Try Google [protobuf-net Serialization](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)